# How to have multiple variable function work with vectors

Tags: function, vector, scilab

I'm having trouble dealing with scilab functions ; I have an output in the form of a 1x6 vector, and I'd like to have a simple way to make it work with a 6 variable function.

```
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6] ;
function z=f(a,b,c,d,e,f)
...
endfunction
f(v) //returns error
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scilab doesn't have a direct analogue of Python's `fcn(*v)` function call that would interpret the entries of v as multiple arguments.

If you want to be able to call your function as either `fcn(1,2,3,4,5,6)` or as `v = 1:6; fcn(v)`, then you'll need to add this clause to its beginning:

```
function z=fcn(a,b,c,d,e,f)
    if argn(2)==1 then
        [a,b,c,d,e,f] = (a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4),a(5),a(6))
    end
// rest of function
z = a+b+c+d+e+f
endfunction
```

Now `v=1:6; fcn(v)` returns 21, just like `fcn(1,2,3,4,5,6)` does.

The condition `argn(2)==1` checks if the function received one parameter instead of expected 6; if this is the case, it assumes it to be a vector. If that vector doesn't have enough elements (6) for the tuple assignment, an error is thrown.